# offset of image in jQuery is not correct after resizing in Chrome and in FF

Tags: jquery, offset

I have a fiddle set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/cYvwb/

The cannon has a point it rotates around, and the beer bottles are "spawning" here. There are many issues before this looks good (I will make them spawn at the cannon "mouth" later) but this is not the issue that is annoying me now.

The issue is that in FF and after window resizing in Chrome, and probably in other browsers I have not tested yet (IE, safari and opera are not installed on the laptop I am currently working on), the offset of the cannon image (#cannon) is set wrong, and I don't know why? Please help! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "the offset of the cannon image is set wrong" ? How should it be ?

Comment: the script functions like this: on click, a beer bottle is launched from the cannon. The bottle is launched from the CENTERPOINTX and CENTERPOINTY variables set in init() function. These are the offset.top and left values from the #cannon image. The way I think the bottles should appear at the point the cannon rotates about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning : this may be only a part of the answer, as there seem to be different problems.

1 ) The first computation is done when images aren't yet loaded. If you replace

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      init();
});
```

with

```
 $(window).load(function() {
       init();
 });
```

Your offset is consistent (resizing a little won't change the offset a lot).

2 ) Don't repeating call the binding functions as it adds handlers instead of replacing them. Most of what is in the "init" function should not be there (or better : use another function, named otherwise, for the resize handler).